# How to read multiple tables separated by tags in the same csv file into R-studio?

Tags: r

I have a csv file in the below format and I want to read that into R studio.The problem I face is that there are multiple table like data within the same file separated by tags enclosed in angle brackets such as `<header>,<member details> etc.`

I want to read each of these tables under the tags `<header>,<member details> etc.` into separate objects in R.How can I do that ?

Please note that there are two `<member details>` tags and  `<total interest>` appears under each `<member details>` tag showing the aggregation sum of `<member details>`

**Data**

```
<header>
id, cust_name
28, Mr.X

<member details>
Account_No,date,balance,interest
12345,23/12/2018,200000,12.0
12345,25/12/2018,300000,13.0

<total interest>
credit, settlement_acc
25,98765

<member details>
Account_No,date,balance,interest
6789,23/12/2018,200000,19.0
6789,25/12/2018,300000,12.0

<total interest>
credit, settlement_acc
31,98765
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

txt <- "
<header>
id, cust_name
28, Mr.X

<member details>
Account_No,date,balance,interest
12345,23/12/2018,200000,12.0
12345,25/12/2018,300000,13.0

<total interest>
credit, settlement_acc
25,98765

<member details>
Account_No,date,balance,interest
6789,23/12/2018,200000,19.0
6789,25/12/2018,300000,12.0

<total interest>
credit, settlement_acc
31,98765
"
fl <- tempfile()
cat(txt, file = fl)
data <- readLines(fl)
idx <- str_detect(data, '^\\s?$')
idx <- which(idx)
data <- data[ -idx ]
idx <- str_detect(data, '<.*>')
idx <- which(idx)
cn <- data[ idx + 1 ]
cn <- lapply(cn, str_split, ',')
cn <- lapply(cn, unlist)
cn <- lapply(cn, str_trim)
mydata <- idx + 2
mydata <- paste0(mydata, ':', c(idx[ -1 ] - 1, length(data)))
mydata <- lapply(mydata, function(x) data[ eval(parse(text = x)) ])
mydata <- lapply(mydata, str_split, ',')
mydata <- lapply(mydata, function(x) rbindlist(lapply(lapply(x, t), data.frame)))
lapply(1:length(mydata), function(i) {
    colnames(mydata[[ i ]]) <<- cn[[ i ]]
})
names(mydata) <- str_replace_all(data[ idx ], '[<>]', '')
print(mydata)
```